# How to draw a 3D shape using Open TK C#

Tags: c#, opengl

I am currently stuck on some work which I cant figure out on how to work out the faces and the vertices or the faces on where they need to go. If someone could be able to explain to me the maths behind the code and how I can work it out to make the hexagon into a 3D that would be great.

thank you

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    initProgram();

    vertdata = new Vector3[] { 

        //new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), // center
        //new Vector3(2.0f, 0f,0f), // right hand side
        //new Vector3(0f,2f,0f), // up

        new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // center point
        new Vector3(2.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // right hand side
        new Vector3(1.0f,1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
        new Vector3(-1.0f,1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
        new Vector3(-2.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // left hand top
        new Vector3(-1.0f,-1.7f,-0.8f),
        new Vector3(1.0f,-1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
    };

    indicedata = new int[]{
        //front
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3,
        //back
        0, 3, 4,
        0, 4, 5,
        //left
        0, 5, 6,
        0, 6, 1,
    };

    coldata = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
        new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f),
        new Vector3( 0f,  1f, 0f),new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
        new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f),
        new Vector3( 0f,  1f, 0f),new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
        new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f)};

    mviewdata = new Matrix4[]{
        Matrix4.Identity
    };

    Title = "Hello OpenTK!";
    GL.ClearColor(Color.DarkTurquoise);
    GL.PointSize(5f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to give you a little more control over your hexagon:

```
points[0] = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
for(int i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
    points[i] = vec3(sin(i/6.0*HEX_SIZE*M_PI),
                    cos(i/6.0*HEX_SIZE*M_PI));
}
```

Basically you are moving 60 degrees at a time and creating a point at the correct location. Your indices look correct if you are creating individual triangles but you could create a triangle fan, (a bit antiquated), using:

```
private short[] indicedata = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 };
...
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, indicedata.length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
```